# Is Webform using datepicker.js?

Tags: 8, webforms

I am trying to create an alert when a date is selected that falls within 30 days of today using the following script:

```
(function ($) {
  $('#edit-select-date').datepicker({

    onSelect: function () {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var today = new Date();

      if ((new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 30)) > date) {
        // Do something here.
        alert(123);
      }
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Unfortunately this is not working and am getting a $(...).datepicker is not a function in dev console. If datepicker.js is not being used is there a way I can have an alert trigger when the date select is +30 days from today?

Comment: Try to take a look here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 1):

Webform provides a fieldable form entity type. And when you add a date field to it (you didn't specify what date field exactly, core, contrib, custom), this date field may make use of a datepicker library.

Speaking of core it most likely is core's `core/jquery.ui.datepicker` library. Which is used for `#type => 'date'` form elements for example.

When you in your custom script want to make use of this datepicker library you need to add it as a dependency. Same as core does:

> ```
> drupal.date:
>   version: VERSION
>   js:
>     misc/date.js: {}
>   dependencies:
>     - core/drupal
>     - core/modernizr
>     - core/jquery.once
>     - core/jquery.ui.datepicker
> ```

See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/core.libraries.yml#L142-150.

---

And maybe you also make your JavaScript look more like in the examples in the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview).